# What is the size of Westeros?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire, geography

I was wondering, what is the size of Westeros?

I am currently re-reading the books and it's kind of hard to keep track of time or distance with all the different POVs.

Knowing how big the continent is, it would be helpful to put things in a better perspective. For example, I have no idea if it took 3 days for the Starks to go from Winterfell to King's Landing, or 3 months.

If you can compare the size to an actual country or region, it would be great.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## TL;DR Version

To sum up the points below:

1. Westeros is roughly equal to size of South America in our world as per the author.
2. Essos is equal to Europe and Asia combined according to the author.
3. And no, GRRM doesn't want you to be sure how long will it take to travel from point A to B. But he has given a pointer to roughly estimate the size if you really want to. That is the length of the wall.

---

## Longer Version

#### How do ASOIAF regions compare to our world?

George R.R. Martin has compared Westeros to South America and Essos to Eurasia . He [said](http://www.westeros.org/Citadel/SSM/Entry/Geography):

> I will post the dates and times of my signing tour in the "touring"
> thread uptopic. Thanks for asking.
>
> As for your other questions (boy, you folks are relentless), **I don't**
> **have the precise population of King's Landing on[sic] the exact area of**
> **Westeros immediately on hand.**
>
> In very general terms, however... King's Landing is more populous than
> medieval London or Paris, but not so populous as medieval
> Constantinople or ancient Rome.
>
> Some readers have likened Westeros to England because they see some
> general similarities in its shape, and in its location off the west
> coast of a larger landmass. The latter is true enough (I don't see the
> former, myself), but **Westeros is much much MUCH bigger than Britain**.
> **More the size (though not the shape, obviosuly) of South America**, I'd
> say.
>
> **The other continent is bigger (Essos), Eurasia size.**
>
> Yes, a league is three miles.

---

#### Should you worry about how long it takes to travel in Westeros and how big it is?

Also George R.R. Martin is deliberately vague about such matters. He said in another [correspondence with the fans](http://www.westeros.org/Citadel/SSM/Entry/2787):

> **I have deliberately tried to be vague about such things, so I don't have obsessive fans with rulers measuring distances on the map and
> telling me Ned couldn't get from X to Y in the time I say he did**.
>
> However, if you really must know, **you can figure out the distances
> for yourself. The Wall is a hundred leagues long. A league is three
> miles. Go from there.**
>
> But if you turn up any mistakes in travel times by using that measure,
> let it be your secret.

---

#### You really wanna know, don't you?

If, to quote GRRM, you are really that obsessed fan, Well put that calculator and ruler back. [Another fan has roughly done the work](https://atlasoficeandfireblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/28/the-size-and-extent-of-westeros/) for you by estimating the size. According to his/her findings:

> **Total length of Westeros from the North Pole to the coast of Dorne:** 5084.06 miles
> **Distance from the Wall to the North Pole:** 2,086.46 miles
> **Distance from the Wall to the treeline in Thenn**: 595.7 miles
> **Distance from the Wall to the Arctic Circle:** 300 miles
> **North-South Distance of the Seven Kingdoms**: 2,997.6 miles
> **North-South Distance of the Lands Beyond the Wall (to the edge of the WoIaF map):** 1,865.2 miles
> **Combined North-South Distance of Mapped Westeros**: 4,862.8 miles

[image]

<sub>**Disclaimer:** These findings are not the official position of the author or the publishers. Any error's responsibility lies with the original poster. To clarify the confusion some members may have, The creator has based his recordings on a common reference system which he established from the Data GRRM has provided, explains his research in detail and identifies the potential issues with his work. I suggest taking a look at his blog post linked above.</sub>.

---

Comment: Related, I've always assumed that, out-of-universe, the unpredictable changes of season were part of this. You can't use the typical sign posts of leaves changing, snow falling, etc, to measure intervals of time.

Comment: @chepner Indeed. I understand the author's desire not to engage in that kind of accuracy and extraneous info. Doing that leaves a lot of room for errors, Makes the author and editors work harder to spot any of such errors, and at the end does not add any significant value to the story.

Comment: GRRM doesn't see the similarities in the shapes of Great Britain and Westeros?? I find that hard to believe: https://www.reddit.com/r/MapPorn/comments/2y4xpm/the_world_of_game_of_thrones_as_ireland_and/

Comment: Ah misunderstood your comment. Yes Its curious that GRRM says he doesn't see physical familiarity in the maps of the two entities

Comment: What north pole? Who said Westeros even _had_ poles, let alone their locations? Is it even known for a fact that Westeros is on a planet in space?

Comment: Of course. Its on the planet of Planetos.

Comment: @einpoklum First of all, Westeros is a continent, not a planet so even suggesting that it has poles is absurd. Secondly, Please read the blog post linked :) You will understand why does the person behind use equator and poles as a common reference to between our world and that one

Comment: Roughly like South America, with a wall at the northern end and horrible creatures on the other side of it, you said?

Comment: @alexgbelov: Is that known for a fact? Has it been proven that when you go far enough in any direction you get to the "other side of the map"?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Lol it's funny but I hope this does not spark a political outrage :P

Comment: It's worth noting that the method used in the linked blog post only works if the map of Westeros is drawn in an equal-distance projection. If it is not, the estimates are probably completely inaccurate because they are made using a far northern landmark for scale. Imagine taking a standard Mercator map and trying to estimate distances around the globe using only Greenland for scale.

Comment: @Joe it's also worth noting that those North distortions generally come because we are mapping a whole globe. For maps dealing with only single continents, especially one that is less wide than tall, this problem disappears quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a fan of the South America comparison. Most of the travel is among the seven kingdoms, and in one case, from the wall northward. I think it is better to compare the length of the regions north of the wall, and south of the wall, to the length Brazil.

Moreover, nobody of any real focus has traveled from The Wall to Dorne in one journey. The North, and the region that the other kingdoms constitute, are about the same size. Accordingly, you might think of each of those two as being approximately the size of Central America (i.e. from Guatemala to Panama).

Comment: People have traveled from Dorne to Wall i.e. King Vorian Dayne and his fellow Dornish Kings (Although they may have taken the naval route). We don't have to like the Writer's ideas but I fear his word is the last word on the matter and only one that matters. If he says Westeros is equivalent in size (Not shape) not South America, that's what it is.

Comment: @Aegon I agree, the author's word is final. However, my comparisons are compatible with his. Central America*2 = Brazil. Brazil*2 = South America = Westeros. Regarding Dayne, I've amended my answer accordingly.

Comment: Aegon -  You're wrong.  The author is not the last word.  Reality and logic are the last words.  In the foreword to Prologue to Foundation Isaac Asimov listed his novels in chronological order of fictional events.  Asimov put The Currents of Space before The Stars Like Dust which is obviously a mistake.  No doubt Asimov would have revised the list if someone had asked him about the error.

Comment: @M.A.Golding If reality and Logic are the last words, a mythical world with dragons and magic wouldn't exist in the first place :) No, Author's choice is the last word on how he hopes to see his world

Comment: Aegon - Asimov clearly wrote his "Empire" trilogy so that The Stars Like Dust happens thousands of years before The Currents of Space that happen thousands of years before Pebble in the Sky.  Asimov simply made a mistake about the order of his own stories.

Comment: Aegon - J.R.R. Tolkien was very careful but I can point out a place where the narrative and the Tale of the Years disagree about the elapsed time.  And places where the narrative and the maps disagree about the geography.  In such situations which is the author's real intention?

Comment: @M.A.Golding Those are errors, not something by-design (In tolkien's case). GRRM himself has made errors e.g. The varying description of Jeyne Westerling before and after capture of Riverrun by Jaime Lannister. GRRM admitted it was a mistake after it sparked a lot of wild theories. However, When GRRM says that Westeros is the size of South America in his mind, that's what it is unless he says otherwise.

Comment: You can view Mistakes and Inconsistencies in Tolkien's works [here](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Mistakes_and_inconsistencies_in_Tolkien's_works). Wouldn't know about Asimov's works as I am not a sci fi fan.

Comment: Aegon - I'm fine with Westeros being the size of South America.  I'm just saying that even the "word of God" can be incorrect within an author's fictional universe and the author is not always right..